# replace ' with \' in apex code

Tags: apex, soql, query, soql-injection, replaceall

i have string variable called "Identifier" which has apostrophe in it.

example: `Identifier = "string's length"`

i need to replace this apostrophe with `"\'"`

the result should be `Identifier = "string\'s length"`

finally i have to use this string variable in a `database.query();`

for example: below is the query string

```
String query = 'Select Id, Identifier__c from CustomObj__c where Identifier__c =' +Identifier;
```

And use this query in `database.query()` like below

```
database.query(query);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String str = 'L\'Oreal'; //<-- get the escaped name

System.debug(str); // <--debug output: L'Oreal

String strEsc = String.escapeSingleQuotes(str); //<-- pass through escape method

System.debug(strEsc); //<-- output: L\'Oreal

String wQuotes = '\'%'+strEsc+'%\''; //<-- try to create just the like string

System.debug(wQuotes);  //<--output: '%L\'Oreal%'

List<Account> accts = Database.query('Select Id FROM Account WHERE Name like \'%'+strEsc+'%\'');
//debug of SOQL statement reads: Select Id FROM Account WHERE Name like '%L\'Oreal%'
```

give try this once.  there is one method that do it for you, **escapeSingleQuotes()** .

Answer (score 7):

There's a method for this: String.escapeSingleQuotes. It's meant to be used to protect against SOQL injection.

```
Identifier = String.escapeSingleQuotes('string\'s length');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one:

```
    identifier.replaceAll('\'','\\'')
```

Comment: It did not work @RRI.

Answer (score 0):

The replacement does not modify the string in place, but rather returns the modified value.

Instead of:

```
   identifier.replaceAll('\'','\\'')
```

Use:

```
 identifier = identifier.replaceAll('\'','\\'')
```